# How to implement function(f)(x)(y, z)(g)(r) in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I have been trying to implement the following function:

```
MonsterFunction(f)(x)(y,z)(g)(r);
```

Where `f` is a function that accepts three parameters. `x, y, z` are the parameters which are passed to the function `f` and all of that is passed to the function `g` and the parameter `r` is also passed to the function `g` and the final result is returned.

I have successfully implemented `MonsterFunction(f)(x)(y,z)`, but I just can not figure out how to implement the above function.

Here is the code for what I have already accomplished:

```
std::function<std::function<int(int, int)>(int)> MonsterFunction(std::function<int(int, int, int)> f){
    return [f](int x1){
        return[f, x1](int y1, int z1){
            return f(x1, y1, z1);
        };
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that I only want to accomplish this with `std::function` and `lambda-closure functions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually did it, after a little break I was able to implement it. It is easy as long as you track the nesting carefully.
Here is my final code:

```
std::function<std::function<std::function<std::function<int(int)>(int(int, int))>(int, int)>(int)> MonsterFunction(std::function<int(int, int, int)> f){
    return [f](int x1){
        return[f, x1](int y1, int z1){
            int result = f(x1, y1, z1);
            return [result](int g(int, int)){
                return[result,g](int r){
                    return g(result, r);
                };
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Now I am able to do calls like this `MonsterFunction(Sum)(5)(5,4)(Multiply)(4)`.

> Edit

As Quentin suggested, using `auto` as the return type makes the function more concise:

```
auto MonsterFunction(std::function<int(int, int, int)> f){
    return [f](int x1){
        return[f, x1](int y1, int z1){
            int result = f(x1, y1, z1);
            return [result](int g(int, int)){
                return[result,g](int r){
                    return g(result, r);
                };
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: I can only recommend that you dump `std::function` and return `auto`.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, that is a great idea, but I wanted to show what the actual return type is.

Comment: The actual return type is *not* `std::function`. A lambda has a unique, unnamed type, that's why you need `auto`. Just document the function clearly.

Comment: The problem is not only with conciseness, but also one of performance